# How do I request data securely via Google OAuth?

Tags: python, oauth

Until recently users of my site were able to import data from Google, via OAuth. However, recently they have received the warning below, in a yellow box, when authorising (although the import still works).

I've also noticed this same warning on Facebook's GMail authenticator!

What's changed / am I missing?

> This website is registered with Google
>   to make authorization requests, but
>   has not been configured to send
>   requests securely.
>
> If you grant access but you did not
>   initiate this request at www.foo.com,
>   it may be possible for other users of
>   www.foo.com to access your data. We
>   recommend you deny access unless you
>   are certain that you initiated this
>   request directly with www.foo.com.

(The site is written in Zope/Python, but the step/documentation I'm missing is more important)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try Googling the error message? Doing so took me to [this page](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto.html), which states:

> Registered with enhanced security: Registered applications **with a security certificate on file** can use secure tokens. The Access Request page removes cautions, displaying this message: " Google is not affiliated with , and we recommend that you grant access only if you trust the site."

See their docs, step 4, "Upload a security certificate" for more details.

Comment: The website states that this is not necessary for the oauth method, only authsub.  I don't see why you're getting this message if you're using a valid consumer key/secret...